# IE7 xml .attr doesn't work

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer-7

Hi I wonder is someone could please help, i'm working on a project and it works fine in IE8 and upwards, firefox, chrome etc but IE7 is causing major problems. The code below in particular is problematic.

```
$(xml).find('Data').each(function () {
      //alert($(this).attr('Passret').val());

        if ($(this).attr('Passret') === 'yespass') {

//do something
}
```

IE7 isn't recongising the if statement because .attr appears to be undefind. Any suggestions?

Here's an example of the xml

```
<Data Passret="yespass" Custref="32"><Query>0.0020s</Query></Data>
```

Kind regards
Rachel

Comment: How are you defining `xml`, and which version of jQuery so we can look for possible fixed bugs?

Comment: hi thanks for your speedy response, i still get  'prop(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: //our url call,
        dataType: 'xml',
        timeout: 5000,
        type: 'post',
        success: loginCheckSuccess, // this is where the above goes
        error: loginCheckError
    });